# What is the possible causes that browser out of memory only when run with testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a test that run 30 times open & close a sub-webpage. And if I manually close and reopen, the web app runs okay, no issues at all.

If I use TestCafe to close and reopen for 30 times, I have error on the browser after around 20 times:
Error code: out of memory. like the screenshot shows.

[image]

And this will make my test hang then disconnect. I wonder is there any difference on TestCafe when storing & removing cache? Has anyone encountered or know about this issue?

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on the environment (website, operation system, hardware, etc.). If it can be reproduced on any machine, please submit an [issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new/choose) to the TestCafe repository.